# How can I avoid unchecked method warnings in Java when I don't know the type of a generic object?

Tags: java, generics, warnings, unchecked

I am new to using Java Generics and am wondering how I should go about getting rid of unchecked method warnings. I understand that code like this specifies the type of the generic object and doesn't give me warnings:

```
DTRowData<String> someData = new DTRowData<String>("Some string");
```

But I won't know the type of my generic object, so I have been writing code like this instead:

```
DTRowData moreData = new DTRowData(80100);
```

This code makes more sense to me, as it seems like a good reason to use generics is if you don't know what type of data you are going to get back. But it gives me the warning: "Unchecked call to DTRowData as a member of raw type DTRowData"

What is the correct way to stop getting this warning, when I won't know what type of data I'll be getting back? Sometimes it will be a number, sometimes a String.
I would prefer not to use

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

Here is my class code if it helps at all:

```
public class DTRowData<E> {
    public E someValue;

    public DTRowDate(E someValue){
        this.someValue = someValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: Generally we use `<?>` wildcard if we don't know specific type. You can also let compiler infer type with diamond operator `<>`. But in case of `new DTRowData(80100)` why not just use `<Integer>`?

Comment: What do you mean by "no idea"? Will you be passed `Object`s only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the statement `DTRowData moreData = new DTRowData(80100);`, you already know the type of the parameter `E`: it is an integer infered from the type of the constructor argument `80100`.

So you can use the generic type as follows:

```
 DTRowData<Integer> someData = new DTRowData<Integer>(80100);
```

Comment: Or `new DTRowData<>(80100)` with Java 7+